# log4j2 - disable dependency service logs logged into my application.log

Tags: logging, log4j2, slf4j

i have a log4j2 setup in my project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="ERROR">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">${sys:root}/logs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="APPLICATION" filePattern="${log-path}/application.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}" >
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %highlight{[%p]} %X{RequestId} (%t) %c: %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="REQUESTLOG" filePattern="${log-path}/access.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}" >
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="APPLICATION"/>
        </Root>

        <Logger name="AccessLogger" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="REQUESTLOG"/>
        </Logger>
 
        <!-- Suppressing excessive logs from dependency packages -->

        <Logger name="com.dependency1" level="OFF"/>
        <Logger name="com.component" level="OFF"/>
    
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

`MyProject` calls `dependecy-1` this calls `dependency-2`

So my `dependency-2` is doing something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < records; i++) {
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.setName("componentRecorder-" + t.getName());
    t.start();
```

In my application log i am seeing things which are published by this thread

```
     (componentRecorder-Thread-21) componentLogger:       
A21TJRUUN4KGV   01016862e1798c145f8a127b53634d3ea788392b8123c4b7f5fd04369e3ebc8c7c75    01015c1148bd32f255852a618717bd606e93b5bd4a172fde2b1995de7babe6b2c6fe        010140600f6b1f1dd9327f1bf19b23c4c2e39efa4077338ca32deca1fbd41c6d4a66
```

Based on this  `(componentRecorder-Thread-21)` componentLogger:

I am assuming that this is logged by above code.

How do i stop this logs going into my application logs. Since these logs dont have class/package name associated with it I am not sure how to suppress this

I want to suppress all logs from `componentRecorder`

My dependecy-2 is using slf4j for logging

Comment: If the message follows the pattern you specified, "componentLogger" is the name of the logger. Just set its level to `OFF`, as you did with other loggers.

Comment: This solved the problem. Please post this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the noisy logger is included in the message: `componentLogger`. You can disable it, as you did with other loggers:

```xml
<Logger name="componentLogger" level="OFF"/>
```